# How to update vaule of an object in nested array, react-redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm trying to update one value of objects that is in the nested array, below is an example of my state.

```
list: {
    '0': {
      name: 'India',
      code: 'IND',
      stateList: [
         '0' : {
              name : 'Karnataka'
              cityList: [
                 '0' : {
                    name : 'Bangalore',
                    population: 1100000
                  }
               ]
         },
         '1' : {
              name : 'Maharastra'
              cityList: [
                 '0' : {
                    name : 'Mumbai',
                    population: 1100000
                  },
                  '1' : {
                    name : 'Nagpur',
                    population: 1500000
                  }
               ]
         }
      ]
    }
```

I want to update population from textbox.
Also if you know any idea to resolve this issue, please let me know.

Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: `population` of which object? All of them? what did you try?

Comment: update population by index.

Comment: Population is in textbox. When I am trying to update, Nagpur population textbox then it will update the redux state and change the population of Nagpur.